# How can I restore a laptop that shipped with Windows 8 back to factory settings after erasing the main OS partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, bios, system-restore

I have a brand new ASUS laptop that came with Windows 8. I am attempting to get rid of Windows 8 and install Windows 7 instead. (I have been able to disable secure boot, and boot from a CD.) I am planning to format the OS partition where Windows 8 is installed, and install Windows 7 there.

However, I want to make sure that it will still be possible to restore the computer to its factory default settings after doing this, in case I am unable to find Windows 7 drivers for important built-in hardware, or need to return the laptop for some reason. It has both a 944 MB "recovery partition" and a 21 GB "restore partition". I am guessing the 21 GB restore partition has everything necessary to wipe everything and make the laptop just as it was when it was bought.

However, every single set of instructions I have been able to find for resetting such a computer to factory settings gives instructions to be carried out from the Windows 8 Desktop, which won't exist after this. Is there a way to get Windows 8 back from the restore partition if I want after wiping the OS partition?

Comment: Use 3rd party software and Image the entire hard drive, you can later restore it to the hard drive if needed. This is the first thing I do when I get a new PC, Image the entire hard drive. I like Acronis but is not free, Macrium Reflect has a free version that is pretty good, whichever you choose be sure to make the bootable media for image recovery purposes.

Comment: Windows 8 drivers and Windows 7 drivers are basically the same. You can almost always force one OS to use the drivers for the other.

Comment: I am glad to know that these partitions make it possible to restore the original windows 8 operating system, but how exactly can I do this without any windows 8 operating system installed?  I have been able to get into the bios, but there is no option in the boot menu for the recovery partition.  All the instructions I can find say something to the effect of "use the refresh tool in windows 8" and tell you how to navigate to it, assuming you have already booted windows 8.  Obviously, this won't be a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You need both partitions: the recovery and the restore. The restore partition contains the original OOBE (out of box experience) Windows operating system image that shipped with the computer. The recovery partition contains the software necessary to extract the OOBE image and deploy it onto your boot partition.

Additionally, you may need to do extra work while or after installing Windows 7 to preserve your ability to boot into the recovery partition... but most likely this his handled by the bios, and just leaving those two partitions alone will be enough.

Comment: I am glad to know that these partitions make it possible to restore the original windows 8 operating system, but how exactly can I do this without any windows 8 operating system installed?  I have been able to get into the bios, but there is no option in the boot menu for the recovery partition.  All the instructions I can find say something to the effect of "use the refresh tool in windows 8" and tell you how to navigate to it, assuming you have already booted windows 8.  Obviously, this won't be a possibility.

Comment: When the computer boots up, watch for a chance to view a one-time boot menu instead of going to the full bios.